# How to make two foreign keys of same Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, foreign-keys

I've got a Model Message, that has `message:text | date_sent:date` as attributes. It should also have `from_member` and `to_member` representing the user that sent the message, and the user that received it.

How can I do that in Rails? I've read that the convention would be `member_id` for a ForeignKey to the model Member. But, what if I want two fields referencing `Member`?

Comment: You can make your has_many / belongs_to associations with custom name and specifying the foreign key. Something like has_many :to_member, foreign_key: :to_member_id, class_name: 'Member'. I have done this thanks to the doc, I'll check to find a link.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the class of the association:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :from_member, class_name: 'Member'
  belongs_to :to_member, class_name: 'Member'
end
```

and

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sent_messages, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: :from_member_id
  has_many :received_messages, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: :to_member_id
end
```

In your database, :messages needs the attributes `:from_member_id` and `:to_member_id`

so in your migration its:

```
def change
  add_column :messages, :from_member_id, :integer
  add_column :messages, :to_member_id, :integer

  add_index :messages, :from_member_id
  add_index :messages, :to_member_id
end
```

Comment: yes or specify the foreign_key you are using (sometimes different names are better for clarity)

Comment: well, Rails is convention over configuration, so don't configure what is defined by the convention. And I see your point. Sometimes it's good to have a hint to remember the convention.

Comment: Yeah I totally agree. Fun we can out with nearly the same answer at the same time! I would just add an index in the migration, I suppose there will be a lot of messages, it's gonna be faster to retrieve the senders/receivers

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this (adjust the typo for your needs and code clarity):

```
message.rb

belongs_to :sender, foreign_key: :sender_id, class_name: 'Member'
belongs_to :receiver, foreign_key: :receiver_id, class_name: 'Member'


member.rb

has_many :message_sent, foreign_key: :sender_id, class_name: 'Message'
has_many :message_reveived, foreign_key: :receiver_id, class_name: 'Message'
```

Then you can do for instance:

```
@message.sender and @message.receiver

@member.message_sent and @member.message_reveived
```

For your migrations:

```
def change
  add_column :messages, :sender_id, :integer
  add_column :messages, :receiver_id, :integer
  add_index :messages, :sender_id
  add_index :messages, :receiver_id
end
```

Comment: What about the generator? How would I specify the fields?

Comment: I usually add those by hand and add an index if needed. Like t.integer :sender_id, index: true

Comment: The generator just add an integer and an index. The rest comes from rails convention (naming ... ). It's easy to reproduce this by hand.

Comment: for the generator you can specify the index like this: rails g model message sender_id:integer:index .....